# Struggling to vertically append a string ( csv file) to an existing matrix in Scilab/matlab

Tags: matlab

```
M=read_csv("Gradesheets\MECN2073_2014.csv")  

disp(size(M,1))



 for x=1:1:size(M,1)

      StudNum=M(x,1)

      Grd=M(x,2) // Grd is grade column in gradesheets hence x,2 (column 2 of Grd )

      if find(StudNum==StudentNumbers)>0 then disp("Exists") 

          H = [StudNum]

          StudentNumbers = [StudentNumbers;StudNum]
      end
end
```

This is where i get error:

> Undefined operation for the given operands.
>   check or define function %s_f_c for overloading.
>   at line      38 of exec file called by :

Comment: There is no `then` in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that StudentNumbers is the vector containing all your existing students right? If so, try the code below and let me know what you get.

```
M=read_csv("Gradesheets\MECN2073_2014.csv")  

storing = [];

for i=1:size(M,1)
  StudNum=M(i,1)

  if find(StudNum==StudentNumbers(i)) == 1

      disp("Exists");
      storing = [storing;StudNum];
  end

end
```